# Where to find/install libpulsecore-1.0.so? Pulse audio problem

Tags: package-management, pulseaudio, skype, libraries

My skype is crashing silently.  I tried to follow advice here:

[What to do when Skype freezes silently?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33773/what-to-do-when-skype-freezes-silently)

and here:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=11653257

But it suggests giving permission to a file called `libpulsecore-1.0.so`

I looked in `/usr/lib/` and it wasn't there.

I tried `sudo apt-cache search libpulsecore-1.0.so` and found nothing.

The tab-autocomplete after typing `libpuls` also didn't return anything, so I believe it is not installed.

I found nothing with `which libpulsecore-1.0.so` and had no google hits for how to find the file, or which package it was in.

How do I install this file?  Sound otherwise works.  (Skype even used to work fine until a couple of weeks ago.)

I'm running 11.10.

Comment: You don't say what version you're running...

Comment: I'm running Oneiric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"looked in /usr/lib/ and it wasn't there."
okay...

"I tried sudo apt-cache search libpulsecore-1.0.so and found nothing."

```
apt-cache search runs as non-root just fine.
It flags mostly on words in the description and words in the package name
```

"which libpulsecore-1.0.so"

```
which is for binaries you run from the CLI
to show 'which' will be executed first with your path settings
```

to find out if you have it:

```
sudo updatedb && locate libpulsecore | grep '.so'
```

to find out what provides it:

```
dpkg -S libpulsecore
```

Looks like the base pulseaudio package on 11.10 which is what I'm running for production until 12.04 goes stable in about a month.

```
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio
```

Done.
EDIT:
if it says you have pulseaudio but you don't have the .so you need a --reinstall switch on the apt-get line

Comment: Yep, good point.  I had poor diagnostics and was looking incorrectly---it was there the whole time.  Thanks!

Comment: not a problem...you'll notice I didn't put the version number in the searches.  this is in case it changes from 1.0 to 2.0 or whatever so you can still find it if there's a version change